# Introduce your self to the BSE-community, it's caretakers and visitors and say "hello" here

Tags: discussion, support

(draft to be modified for use as featured meta topic to be seen here when in desktop mode. Also good, if wishing for such, if the moderators create a new question, copy it if fine modified, and delete this one as it would be not proper if a monk invites)

[image]

Welcome to the BSE-community here!

We, and you as well, are given by the owner of SE to make use of this environment in relation with the Tripple Gems and the Buddhas Teachings.

Sure we would be happy to get you known a little and it's good to be aware not just communicate with avatars.

Feel free to give a short hello or extended introduction to your person, your wishes your aims... likes and dislikes and by it give others also the opportunity to welcome you as well in putting comments under your post or just up-vote it.

If you like, and such is always of help, you may also add your age, gender and stage of practice or knowledge in Dhamma, even a picture of yours and your life and environment.

If wishing that others may be able to access your topic here, just put a link to it on your accont profile.

The better you know another, the better another knows you, the more effective the support and the lesser the dangers of wrong deeds for everyone, out of wrong perceptions.

(if wished some explaining in regard of the importance of the practice of apacayana, one of the 10 ways of making merits and a matter of Sila in doing such proper *(Note that this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks, entertainment and akusala deeds, but as a share of merits and to continue such for release)*)

Comment: Maybe the generous members of the long term moderation and initiation team likes to start with a generouse introduction as sample. Ven. Yuttadhammo, Upasika Lanka , @ChrisW , Andrei , Sirinath ... not sure if mention of more would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

**BSE-Community, it's inrtoduction, welcome and history**

### The worldly base as generosity for this realm

Buddhism-Exchange is a child of the "Brahma-Realm" occupied, founded, by Mr. [Joel Spolsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky) (born 1965, Jewish) & Mr. [Jeff Atwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood) (born 1970, US), with there platforms of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/company), Stack Exchange (Q&A Sites, previous just programmer exchange) in 2008.

In this realm resist the Group of [Area51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/), busy in seeking after new "empty Brahmarealms", refined areas for existing.

End of Juli 2013, some of the Devas, rejoicing on and in creations, dwelling in the various sections of this world, seemingly thought of giving Buddhism SE rise to develop, at least to pull the [Buddha-Dhammas Realm and nurishment](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/index_en.html) into, as new particular [plane of existence](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka_en.html) and put on a purposal...

---

### This have been the main initiators who took on the possibility of creation

Initial creator of [BSE-porposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism), request for BSE, was made by "Hamlet", a mysterious inactivated useraccount and later edited by "Upasaka" [MatthewMartin](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/4085/matthewmartin), [image] (a secular Buddhist at this time).

[Ven. Yuttadhammo](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/18/yuttadhammo) [image], programmer and user of the worldly offers of SE, joined the work for the porposal as the fist "Buddhist" with formal relation to the Buddha, and became later one of BSEs fist members and engaged moderator for the lay community.

Mr. [Adam Lear](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/1/adam-lear), suff-member, set up the community after success in porposal and Mr. [Jon Ericson](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/2/jon-ericson), (SE stuff member, bible-commentor) was the first [community manager](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do/99341#99341) of BSE, followed by Mr [Shog9](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/3/shog9)... (more: see url user no. 1,2...). Mr. [bytebuster](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/4/bytebuster), a political freedom-fighter, the first not by the gift of the site owner appointed, member....

...
...dedicated, changed, user, worthy to note...

**current Moderators**

Name - link

(initial sketch for a community introductions and history, maintained by the initiators, moderators and members)

Comment: May Upasaka @Suminda Sirinath S. Dharmasena feels inspired to sacrifices here his knowledge.

Comment: Maybe Nyom @ChrisW likes to add his site info knowledge, the not-system one here and divides himself a little from the world he resists and feeds on.

Comment: Householder @MatthewMartin seems to be one of the founders who owes gratitude for efforts. Maybe BSE-Brahma likes to add some about the past merits.

Comment: Some people put information on their user profile -- [MatthewMartin](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/289/matthewmartin?tab=profile) for example. Also note on the right-hand side of that page, "Last seen Nov 20 '17 at 3:54" means he hasn't visited this Meta site (while logged in) since 2017 ... that's his meta-profile, conversely his [profile on the main site](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/289/matthewmartin?tab=profile) shows his most recent visit there was July 12 2019. His profile also has links to his writings on other sites.

Comment: Sadhu the care, Nyom Chris. What does Nyom think, do fellows, co-students, have responsibilities in the Buddas communities?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe householder @Caleb is also one of the first hours.

Comment: I think there were 214 users -- [listed here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110?page=22&phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top) -- who expressed an interest in the site before the site was started. It took a year for that many users to find the proposal and "commit" to it. I don't recognise most of the user names on that list, but I recognise some -- anyone there would be one of the "first" users.

Comment: I don't see a way to display the list of users sorted by the date they joined, but you sort of see the date at which someone joined in their user profile. And yes [Caleb Paul's profile](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/31/caleb-paul?tab=profile) says `Member for 5 years, 1 month` -- which means the start date was 2014-06-17 -- which was the date on which the first user account were created (so, yes, one of the first users).

Comment: The list shows the first at last, Seems that householder @GreenMatt was the first in 2013, but not clear who initated it, maybe only Nyom Matthew Martin

Comment: Bhante @yuttadhammo was seemingly the 5th, so possible within the starter group coming anywhere from it things.

Comment: Nyom @AndreiVolkov joined a month later.

Comment: One day later -- [Jul 31 '13](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110?page=18&phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top) instead of July 30. His comment says, "I'm an active participant in Buddhism Q&A group on Google+ but I consider StackExchange a far superior platform. Would love to answer some questions!" so I suppose there was or is a "Buddhism Q&A group on Google+" before this site began. And Andrei was one of the first users of this site, i.e. with a profile dated 2014-06-17.

Comment: He banned my person there years ago, yes (still just a homeless). Not sure if that still runs. Bhante Yuttadhamma, had similar over there, similar ways.

Comment: This is the first time I've moderated a site. And it's the first time I found an online site where people answer questions about Buddhism, though I've participated on other onlne sites (all about software development) since the early 1990s.

Comment: When I read people's posts here on Meta I gathered that a lot of users (see e.g. [here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1763/254) and [here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/100/254)) had some experience with previous sites -- "arguing" and "put-downs" and so on -- and hoped that this site could be different. Perhaps this site's being "Q+A" instead of "discussion" helps to keep users from criticising each other, and more focused on helping the OP.

Comment: Bhava tanha, sure. But thats not that bad, Birth is prerequisite of release. And much desire for controll being the drive.

Comment: Most are not so interested to get other culturs, traditions known, but like to overtake other domains `finding and rehabilitating all the good parts of Buddhism to make them compatible with my sense of modernity, science and progressive western values.`, pull it in rather to use it for an escape. Open-source-culture is surely main founder.

Comment: When you wrote `still just a homeless`, should I understand that as your saying that you were not ordained back then, and are now?

Comment: Yes, although already wanderer under the Gems, not wearing the robes of the Arahats, not having joined and outwardly Sangha. In Vinaya-language maybe a not perfect ordained, usually called 10 sila Anagarika. Before intensiver n Dhamma, btw., never used/accessed any online community or online social network. Must have been 2011,12, having taken birth at DW. Google+ was new at the time and became larger alternative to blogging, good householder.

Comment: I really don't think the original community intended this site to be used for blogging, Bhante, not a blog at all, not a "larger alternative" but something different. Everyone seemed to agree with the answers to [this topic](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/170/254), e.g. "beginner's questions" are permitted (even welcome) if they're asked by a beginner -- but some users see "seeded" question are just a "chore", like answering a quiz.

Comment: One can be sure that 99% of users here are total beginners and neither Faith-, Dhamma- or firm followers. But it runs of topic here. How ever, the desire of becoming is always similar to blogging, in what ever disguise. That being the case, question and answering is the tradition of even the Arahats who wouldn't need it any more, to keep the Dhamma alive and to sharpen the skills.

Comment: Maybe moderator @AdamLear might be able to fill up graps about the main giver.

Comment: Adam (and [Abby](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7/hairboat?tab=profile) and [Catherine](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/13974/catija) too) are SE employees. I guess existing SE employees get user profiles on each new SE site when it's created (and new SE employees get a profile on every existing site).

Comment: My person guesses that it is enought of "that would be good" - as a matter of good conduct - animation and leaves it here as possibility to make merits or demerits, at this point. Btw: see the way of introduction and approach of professionals: not the Uposatha of the Jains, even if after good gains in the world. 'Who feels well when: `Apparently, this user, giver, receiver, prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.`, who is attracted?

Answer (score 0):

**BSE-Community, it's introduction, welcome and history**

I didn't initiate the site.

There's a record of the site's "definition phase" on SE's [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110?phase=definition) -- where people proposed and commented on what kind of questions the site might welcome -- I haven't read this and don't know it, it doesn't directly affect my decisions.

I don't know how (nor which) people communicated with each other about the site, before it existed.

You can also see some of the site's earliest meta-topics -- [this is page 9](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110?phase=definition) for example, see also page 8 etc.

Ven. Yuttadhammo is [no longer an active user](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1711/254) of the site, hardly ever posts posts now, perhaps he may read something sometimes but there's no reason to assume he will.

Robin111 wrote a [Welcome to Buddhism.SE!](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1506/254) (I see that she too hasn't visited the site recently).

---

**Feel free to give a short hello or extended introduction to your person, your wishes your aims**

Hello. :-)

I'm not eager to post "my" personal history, unless sometimes a little bit of it seems relevant for helping to answering a question. They say that a "good" answer is based on something ...

> - Something that happened to you personally
> - Something you can back up with a reference

I even find inoccuous questions like "How are you?" confusing, sometimes impossible to answer in writing! (in person or by phone is different case)

I'm about 12 years older than you are, as far as I know -- in case that helps anything.

---

**current Moderators**

The up-to-date list of moderators is here: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

I [accepted](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1515/254) nomination as a moderator -- because a site cannot exist without moderation, and I'm grateful that the site exists and that people remain willing to use it

I don't enjoy acting as moderator much -- the arising of a need to moderate is dukkha, isn't that so? -- I'm glad the site exists though, and I hope I'm properly grateful to people who try to answer questions.

I think we're fortunate that a very large majority of users are moderate and polite already, and don't need to "be moderated".

The site has been active for about 5 years now, and people rarely post or vote on Meta now.<sup>1</sup>

I think that SE's principal rules are:

- It's a question-and-answer site, not a discussion forum
- Be nice, be welcoming, and focus on the content not the user

This site is unusually permissive about what questions are asked -- [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1558/moderation-policies-for-questions) -- the following are both allowed:

- Questions about Buddhist doctrine which may not relate to any immediate practical problem
- Questions about about immediate or personal practical problem for which the OP wants some answer from Buddhist doctrine

I also compiled a while ago a [FAQ index (summary of site policies)](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2106/254) which is a summary of several policies which "the community" discussed and voted when Meta was more active.

If you can agree to those policies when you use the site -- and avoid directly criticising other users, though your answers may sometimes contradict theirs or offer an alternate view -- perhaps that's good for everyone.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The "Views" (e.g. "20 views" for this question at the time of writing) suggest people visit and read without posting: but perhaps that's an over-estimate and it's fewer users reading the same post more than once, though with a delay like [more than 15 minutes between views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/139866).</sub>

Comment: Sadhu for the generosity to introduct your self a little and clear that Nyom Chris's relation to this world is a huge "love-affair". May he always enjoy his good undertakings and sometimes also let go of holding his "honey" to strong.

Comment: Importand for other users, to fall not into a wrong doing: Householder Chris has been born around 1960, (especial for younger)

Comment: @ChrisW Your intentions, commitment and patience is appreciated!

Comment: Thank you, Erik.

Comment: Didn't  you happen to you personally?

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if it is possible to delete all my exchanges, answers and comments. I don't feel participating in this way is good for my practice. I am not a Buddhist, nor a teacher and don't wish to leave my kamma on the internet permanently.  Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: I see you have already deleted several answers -- is that enough? Deleting everything usually gets flagged by the system, as "vandalism". You can also, if you want to, delete your account but leave the content that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

As it is not only custom but also a kind of showing appreciation for certain goodness, my person let's known his leave here.

May all your good undertakings always bear their fruits quick and traceable so that conviction into good and skilful soon reaches the point where the journey toward liberation beginns.

Metta & Mudita
SJ