# Should incorrect information be edited?

Tags: discussion, editing

[Information requested on Buddhist monks self-immolation mental technique](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/30928/13525)

This question has an incorrect piece of information:

> Thích Quảng Đức was a monk who immolated himself to protest against the repression by the **Viet Cong** in 1963.

As a Vietnamese and have read some information about him, I think I know the history better. Should I edit it? The bit is unimportant anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can edit anything to make it clearer.

See also these Help topics ...

- [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/editing)
- [Edit Questions And Answers](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)

... perhaps especially, [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11474/139866)

The main restriction is, I think, is that you should avoid making edits which contradict what the author wants to say (this is [sometimes called](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180088/139866) "a hostile edit").

- For example if I post that the moon is 38000 km away then that's probably a typo and I'd like you to edit to correct that, i.e. I'd agree that the correction would improve the quality of my post.
- Or (I can't think of a good example but) if I say that the moon is made of cheese then perhaps that's my actual opinion and/or what I really intend to post, and I wouldn't welcome your editing it. In that case maybe a comment might be better than contradicting the OP -- like, "I don't think it's made of cheese", or perhaps better a question, "why did you say that?", or, "isn't it [iron-rich rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_structure_of_the_Moon), like the Earth is?"

Generally though if it's a minor edit then that's welcome.

If it's an answer then another option is to post another (less misleading) answer of your own.

If it's a question then another option is to say "I don't understand this question".

Sometimes too it's because they misunderstood something that the author posted a question, and in that case the appropriate response might be to answer the question instead of editing it (but beware [Answers vs Advice](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/254) i.e. don't post an answer like, "that's the wrong question" without answering it, and also maybe avoid posting a comment which answers the question).